# Conversion of tensorflow float32 is incompatible with a java object

Tags: java, android, python-3.x, tensorflow

Error:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert between a TensorFlowLite tensor with type FLOAT32 and a Java object of type java.lang.String (which is compatible with the TensorFlowLite type STRING).

I have built a neural network from my dataset and have 2 layers then I have saved the model as h5 and then converted it into tflite using tf.keras model and conversions but when I deploy it in the application it gives me the above error

I have tried inputting with a lot of type of arrays and array lists

Error:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert between a TensorFlowLite tensor with type FLOAT32 and a Java object of type java.lang.String (which is compatible with the TensorFlowLite type STRING).

```
model.add(layers.Dense(500, input_dim=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation= "relu"))
model.summary() #Print model Summary
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X_train,Y_train,epochs=1000,validation_split=0.3)
```

How I convert:-

```
from tensorflow.contrib import lite
converter = lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file( 'Model.h5')
tfmodel = converter.convert()
open ("model.tflite" , "wb") .write(tfmodel)
```

Implementation to android

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("-0.5698444");
list.add("-0.57369368");
list.add("-1.31490297");






try (Interpreter interpreter = new Interpreter(mappedByteBuffer)) {
    interpreter.run(list, "output");
}


private MappedByteBuffer loadModelFile() throws IOException {
    AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = getAssets().openFd("model.tflite");
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
    FileChannel fileChannel = inputStream.getChannel();
    long startOffset = fileDescriptor.getStartOffset();
    long declaredLength = fileDescriptor.getDeclaredLength();
    return fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, startOffset, declaredLength);
}
```

Comment: It will be helpful if you post the code used to load the data in the TFLite model in Java.

Comment: Hi, I have added that part

Answer (score 0):

Found the mistake. In the line,

```
try (Interpreter interpreter = new Interpreter(mappedByteBuffer)) {
    interpreter.run(list, "output");
 }
```

The 2nd argument for the `interpreter.run()` has to be a `float[]` and not `"output"`. The `float[]` will be populated with the class probabilities when the model is run.

The correct method to provide inputs and outputs to the `interpreter.run()` method:

```
Interpreter interpreter = new Interpreter(mappedByteBuffer)

float[][] inputs = new float[1][num_features]
// populate the inputs float array above
float[][] outputs = new float[1][num_classes]

interpreter.run( inputs , outputs )

float[] classProb = outputs[0]
```

Comment: Hi I tried using my shape of tensor it is saying is (0,1) while my java's is (1,1)